# Adding a product to cart using rules

Tags: rules, ubercart

How do I add a product to cart using Rules & Ubercart in Drupal? My aim is to add a product to cart when someone has an weight order total equal 1 kg during checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve it by this way. 
Get cart contents using **uc_cart_get_contents();**. Then calculate total weight of products in your cart and add product using **uc_cart_add_item();** according to your conditions.

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion but my issue is to add products to cart using drupal rules and ubercart modules. My issue is still on. can you suggest a way using rules?

Comment: try it by using custom php as action of your rule. use **uc_cart_add_item();** in php script with product nid as parameter

Comment: @aby did you done it using custom module..??